# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: niallc]
[image: kevisnky]
[image: Stephie]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why we eventually hold elections.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Let's also thank these other users for having stepped up to help moderate this community in the past:

[image: wax eagle]
[image: Tea Drinker]
[image: Lorem Ipsum]

Comment: Why is the sentence "election will be held in few weeks" replaced with "elections will be eventually held"?

Comment: @AleksandarM because the original post is from a long time ago when beta sites were expected to graduate after ninety days or fail, and graduate sites have elections (some pilot betas held elections, but that’s currently not planned for us or others I know of). In the meantime, the policy has changed and beta sites can remain in the same state as long as a minimum of conditions is fulfilled. I changed the text to reflect the current situation.

Comment: You can find more details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites

Comment: I find it troublesome to use an announcement from years ago, edit it, and post as a new announcement. In my view, the old announcent should have been left as it was, and the new one created from scratch (with possible help of copy/paste).

Comment: I wish you apply the same criterium for all 'non-answers' here. @Stephie

Comment: @AleksandarM you may safety assume that I - and the whole mod team - will do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you temporary mods for volunteering your precious time!  Our veteran mod, Niall C., is a great leader, and perfect example of what a mod should be. He handles the site with an expert hand. As a mentor, his "teach a man to fish..." attitude strengthens us. If pinged to chat, he comes quickly, and is always patient. Stephie and kevinsky have the same qualities, and have been using them "unofficially" for a long time. I'm so excited and proud to have them join the mod team! Our great site can only get better under this leadership! I humbly thank you all!