# Additional Moderators Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

> **The new replacements have been picked.** See [the updated Meta announcement](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/148/10996) for details.

---

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, I need to appoint two provisional Moderators to help moderate this site.

**We recently had 2 moderators step down from this site. As discussed in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/208518), just about the only criterion remaining to keep a site open is having enough users (three minimum) willing to step up to moderate it.**

### WE NEED YOUR HELP!

Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

Comment: Who are the current moderators, and who are those we already know don't want to be one?

Comment: Oh, this has already been taken care of! I shoulda linked to the updated Meta announcement; doing that right now ;)

Answer (score 11):

I would like to nominate myself as a moderator.  I have been active on the site since the early days and am still on the site on a regular basis.  Although I no longer work as a commercial landscaper I still garden and am regularly surprised that those tiny seedlings [got out of hand](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/30165/499).  I use [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851930/kevinsky) every day but prefer the Gardening and Landscaping forum for those really tough questions where the answers aren't in the manual.

I can be active most days from 7pm onwards Eastern Standard Time.  As our previous and current moderators have done a great job I cannot promise anything "new" other than helping users do the best thing in the forum.

Answer (score 9):

I’m [Stephie](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/7456/stephie) and nominate myself as moderator for Gardening SE.

After three and a half years on the site, I feel I have got a good idea of how this specific corner of Stack Exchange works. I want to help this comunity grow (no pun intended) and remain healthy, even in its beta state. And who knows? Perhaps we’ll see it graduate one day?

My gardening philosophy is “Let nature do its thing, gently guide, nurture and support what’s growing happily together, but be ruthless if something threatens to smother the rest.” and I feel this pretty much fits for the site as well.

I have been an elected moderator on Seasoned Advice for a few months now, so I’m not just familiar with the theory, but also with the daily tasks of being a mod, from flag-handling over guiding new users to “tough love” where needed. I leaned a lot from my fellow moderators, both on Seasoned Advice and across the network, and appreciate the support that’s always available if needed.

Feel free to ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed) if you have questions (or just want to chat) or leave a comment.